# finding joint Moment generating function of $U,V$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moment-generating-function

suppose $X_1, X_2$ are independent random variable of $N(0,1)$.
suppose $$U=X_1+X_2, V=X_1^2+X_2^2$$ how can I calculate joint Moment generating function of $U,V$

Comment: You should tag this as self-study

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate 
$E[e^{sU}e^{tV}] = E[e^{sX_1 + tX_1^2 + sX_2 + tX_2^2}] 
= E[e^{sX_1 + tX_1^2}]E[e^{sX_2 + tX_2^2}]$.
So, set up the two integrals using the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and then use the technique of *completing the square* in the exponent to evaluate the integrals.